# Select fast 10 rows from 60.000 rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I force with PHP a SQL query, to skip reading 60.000 rows!
I need to select just 10 first rows and it takes lifetime!

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_premium_articles` ORDER BY `id_p` DESC LIMIT 10
```

Is there any way to bring it query in one second?

Comment: Add output of `show create table tbl_premium_articles;`  I'm almost sure you have no index defined on it.

Answer (score 1):

For this query:

```
SELECT pa.*
FROM `tbl_premium_articles` pa
ORDER BY pa.id_p DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

You want an index on `tbl_premium_articles(id_p)`.

Comment: Still it takes sooo long to query 60.000 than it displays 10 rows!!

Comment: The answer above should have worked as there is an index on order_by column, and should do the index scan vs a full table scan, does it optimize it at all @Flamur Beqiraj? check this resource : https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/09/01/mysql-order-by-limit-performance-optimization/